# Trying to install Korean (hangul) input - Lubuntu 14.04

Tags: lubuntu, keyboard-layout, korean

As the subject line says, I've been trying to get Korean keyboard input running on Lubuntu 14.04. There are similar questions about Korean (hangul) that have already been asked and answered, but my problem seems different; more importantly, it isn't resolved by following the recommended steps.

Most methods seem to indicate installing Korean within the language support menu (which I have) and the installing ibus-hangul (which I have).

The next step of the conventional wisdom is to use Terminal or the UI to get to the "Input Method" tab of ibus-setup, and from there use the "Add" button or dropdown to actually add Korean (hangul) to the list of layouts I can use.

The problem is that for me, Korean (hangul) appears NOWHERE, and the "Add" button is actually ghosted out. The box for "Korean" is checked under language support, im-hangul is installed, ibus is otherwise working fine.... I'm at wit's end.

I'm fairly new to Linux, so please let me know if I need to call up some sort of log or report from Terminal to get more directed help.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a little flag or initials on the right side of the LxPanel.  Right click it and choose "Keyboard Layout Handler" Settings.  Uncheck Keep system Layouts (under Advanced setxkbmap Options).  Then add Korean and place it where you want it (using the up and down arrows.)  Before you close the window, make sure you re-check Keep system Layouts.  Then you can close the window.  It will not take effect until the next session.

Comment: Thanks Rex... this might get me closer to the actual problem. I don't see a flag on the right side of the panel. I don't recall messing too much with the panel applets, but I definitely took some things out. I'll check to see if I can add it back, and try your suggestion.

Comment: An update - I re-added the layout handler applet to the panel, and followed your instructions. They seemed to work: I can see both the Korean flag in the corner when I use the keyboard toggle shortcut, and Ibus also shows "Korean" is selected, and Korean is one of the layouts now present in the ibus list.

However... I can still only type in English, even when both ibus and the lxde handler show Korean is selected. Any thoughts?

Comment: Something is not right.  I have added and deleted languages and they have just worked.  Did you reboot?  It will not work without a new session.  Is Korean the default?  Was Korean the installed language?  Is the language pack for Korean installed?

Comment: Thanks again Rex.

English (US) is the default language of the system and the keyboard input. As far as I can tell, I properly installed the Korean language package (through the Language Support under Preferences), as well as the ibus-hangul package through Lubuntu Software Center. And yes, I rebooted the system as you (and the system dialog) told me to.

I'll keep poking away at this, but thanks for your help thus far!